# validar un campo editText vacío

Tags: java, android, validación

Cuando presiono el botón me da error y cierra la aplicación. Funciona bien pero cuando presiono el botón sin datos en los EditText no funciona.

```
    editAncho = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAncho);
    editLargo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLargo);
    editCant = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCant);
    btnCalcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);

    rMedida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rMedida);
    rCantidad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rCantidad);



    btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            int ancho = Integer.valueOf(editAncho.getText().toString());
            int alto = Integer.valueOf(editLargo.getText().toString());
            int cant = Integer.valueOf(editCant.getText().toString());
            int resultado = ancho + alto;

            // aquí deseo comprobar que los ancho , alto , cantidad no estén vacíos

            rMedida.setText("" + (ancho));
            rCantidad.setText("" + cant);

            if (cant == 1)
                rCantidad.setText("" + cant);
            else
                rCantidad.setText("" + (cant));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo personalmente haría una comprobación de si el `EditText` está vacío antes de hacer una conversión de tipos (en tu caso a Integer), ya que en tu caso si el contenido está vacío lo más seguro es que te de un error de conversión de tipos y por eso se detiene tu app cuando le das al botón.

Te dejo a continuación un ejemplo de cómo podrías comprobar que los `EditText` están vacios:

```
btnCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String et_ancho = editAncho.getText().toString();
            String et_alto = editLargo.getText().toString();
            String et_cant = editCant.getText().toString();

            if("".equals(et_ancho ) || "".equals(et_alto ) || "".equals(et_cant )){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"algun campo vacio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     
            }else{

                 int ancho = Integer.valueOf(et_ancho );
                 int alto = Integer.valueOf(et_alto );
                 int cant = Integer.valueOf(et_cant );
                 int resultado = ancho + alto;

                 rMedida.setText("" + (ancho));
                 rCantidad.setText("" + cant);

                 if (cant == 1)
                     rCantidad.setText("" + cant);
                 else
                     rCantidad.setText("" + (cant));
            }  
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo haría una función llamada validarDatos. Básicamente verificara que todos los campos contengan un numero (suponiendo que tienes configurado tu `editText` solo para números)

```
 public void validarDatos() {

  int ancho = Integer.valueOf(editAncho.getText().toString());
  int alto = Integer.valueOf(editLargo.getText().toString());
  int cant = Integer.valueOf(editCant.getText().toString());

  if (ancho.length() == 0) {
      ancho.setError("Ingrese un nombre numero valido");
  } else if (alto.length() == 0) {
      alto.setError("Ingrese un un numero valido");
  } else if (cant.length() == 0) {
      cant.setError("Ingrese un numero valido");
  } else {    
      rMedida.setText("" + (ancho));
      rCantidad.setText("" + cant);    
  }

}
```

Luego llamas la funcion en el `Onclick`

Answer (score 2):

Has probado a tratar la excepción con

```
Boolean error;

    do{
    error=false;
    try{
    //Aquí introduces tu código, donde te da el error.
    }Catch(Exception e){
    //No recuerdo como era para hacer la pantallita de menaje en java pero:
    MessageBox.Show("No hay valor introducido");
    }
    }while(error);
```

Así te aseguras de que el programa no termine, tal vez simplemente con el try catch puedes igualar `label1=" ";`

Comment: Aritz, se agradece tu contribución, pero es importante ver las etiquetas y la información de la pregunta, esto es para JAVA, saludos!